# Finding the remainder when $N$ is divided by $1000$

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there are $N$ ordered lists of positive integers $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6)$ such that $a_i \geq i$ for $i = 1,2,\ldots,6$ and $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5 + a_6 \leq 40.$ Find the remainder when $N$ is divided by $1000.$

Comment: Have you heard of stars and bars?

Comment: Yes, but I am unsure how to apply it here.

Comment: Make new variables that are the excess of the $a$s over their minimum and update the $40$ appropriately

Comment: How exactly does that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint

Let $b_i = a_i - i$

This problem is equivalent to

$$b_1 + b_2 + b_3 + b_4 + b_5 + b_6 \leq 19$$

$$ b_i \geq 0$$

This is a standard problem that you should know how to solve to get $N$